# ProgressDialog setMessage is blank

Tags: android, progressdialog

This has been driving me nuts and I cannot find an answer anywhere. A very simple spinner dialog, but the setMessage is not working, it's blank!

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ProgressDialog loadingProgress;

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            loadingProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            loadingProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
            loadingProgress.setMessage("Loading");
            loadingProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        }
```

In AsyncTask I just show the ProgressDialog:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    loadingProgress.show();
}
```

The result is this:

[image: blank spinner]

Blank, nothing... Doesn't matter if it's simulator or device...  Any ideas why? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and saw the "Loading" string is displayed very well.
Seeing that your screenshot has the space of textview, i think it will be the problem of text color or theme.

If setMessage works, you can detect in "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator" tool of device tab in Eclipse like following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yes, theme it was. What's odd is that ProgressDialog with ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL was displaying text just fine, but ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER was picking color from the theme. Go figure.

Comment: So what you need to do is declare your theme when you create your Progress Dilog. Like:  loadingProgress = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I am using in my app. It works well -- a spinner with a message. The main differences between what you show and this are: 1) I'm using a DialogFragment; 2) I don't call setProgressStyle. Not sure which (if either) of these matter, but this code definitely is working for me.

```
public void showProgressDialog(int stringResId, boolean isCancelable) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, getString(stringResId));
    arguments.putBoolean(EXTRA_CANCELABLE, isCancelable);
    DialogFragment fragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    showDialog(fragment);
}

public static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        String message = arguments.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, null);
        boolean isCancelable = arguments.getBoolean(EXTRA_CANCELABLE, true);

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        if (message != null) {
            dialog.setMessage(message);
        }
        dialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(isCancelable);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```